# Memcached installed (In theory), PHP unable to use memcache_connect()

Tags: php, caching, memcached, centos, pear

Just finished installing libevent(1.4.8), memcached(1.4.5), pear, and libmemcached(0.40) to my lamp server (running PHP 5.2.10 & Centos 5.5 Final), and as far as I can tell, everything installed correctly (was able to address all errors during installation).

However, after finally getting everything updated and installed... upon attempting either of the following:

```
$test=memcache_connect('127.0.0.1', 11211); // OR

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211)
```

I get the errors:

Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found (or) Fatal error: Call to undefined function memcache_connect()

I'm (admittedly) not very good with linux at this point, although after setting this server up completely from scratch, i'm certainly making headway in the education process :) Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: phpinfo() Shows memcached is enabled]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You installed the [Memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) client (not the [Memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) client, which is, very confusingly, also a [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) client). Use the [Memcached class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php) instead.

In case you're wondering what the difference between the two clients is: here's a nice [comparison table](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/PHPClientComparison).

Comment: Oh my gosh... thank you! I am temporarily more confused, however http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php](http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php) has helped a great deal so far. 

Correct me if i'm wrong, but it seems that memcached replaces memcache? Or are they completely separate? Either way, thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not really a replacement, just a different approach to implementing a PHP client for Memcached. Depending on your needs, you can use either client.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you still need pecl/memcache or pecl/memcached (Client/php end)

pecl/memcached will use libmemcached.

pecl/memcache doesn't have that dependency.

```
Some of notes on how to install pecl/memcached
Yum install:
   * memcached
   * memcached-devel
   * php-pear
   * php-devel
   * gcc
   * gcc-c++
   * zlib-devel

Download libmemcached from: http://download.tangent.org/
Configure, Make, Make  install
pecl install memcached
added "extension=memcached.so" to php.ini
```

Comment: Thank you! This, along with Victor's answer helped me figure it out.

$mc=new Memcached; worked perfectly. Thanks again!